# The combined probability of a continuous variable that is also a parameter for a discrete random variable.

Tags: probability, continuous-variables

I have a problem involving the combination of a continuous random variable and a discrete random variable, where the continuous variable also serves as a parameter to the distribution of the discrete variable.

Let's denote the continuous variable by $T$, whose probability density function is some given function $f:\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$.
Furthermore, let's denote the family of discrete random variables by $X_t$, whose probability mass functions are some given family of functions $g_t:\mathbb{Z}\to[0,1]$, where $t\in\mathbb{R}$ is a parameter.

I now have the following event $A$:
\begin{equation}
A=\bigcup_{t\in[t_1,t_2]}\left(T=t\cap X_t=k\right),
\end{equation}
where $t_1,t_2\in\mathbb{R}$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ are given and $t_2>t_1$.
Also, the events $T=t$ and $X_t=k$ are given to be **independent** for all $t\in[t_1,t_2]$.

What I want to know, is how to calculate the probability of $A$.
My intuition tells me that
\begin{equation}
P(A)=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}f(t)g_t(k)\,dt.
\end{equation}

To get there, I did the following:

1. I interpreted $P(T=t)$ as the infinitesimal probability $dP(T<t)=\frac{dP(T<t)}{dt}dt$
2. I used the fact that $T=t$ and $X_t=k$ are independent, so $P(T=t\cap X_t=k)=P(T=t)P(X_t=k)$.
3. I used the fact that all the events in the union in the definition of $A$ are mutually exclusive, so we may sum, or integrate, the probabilities.

The first of these steps is not rigorous at all. It is at best an intuitive idea (although I am far from certain whether it can even be considered correct).

My question essentially is, how do I (somewhat) rigorously find an explicit formula for $P(A)$? I should note that I have only very little experience with formal probability theory, so please excuse my perhaps incorrect use of terms or concepts.

Thank you!